# How to Convert Int into Time in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have integer values like 06,07,08,.....,16,17,18,...

I want to convert this integer values to 24 hour time format.

I am doing something like this

```
//fromTime holds one of the integer value.
DateTime fromTimeDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fromTime.ToString(), 
                                              "HH", 
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  

string fromtimestring = fromTimeDate.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

But it is giving Error

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

while parsing.

What I am doing wrong here. ?

Comment: on which line your getting error?

Comment: I am getting error at 1st line.

Comment: Your code works, so there must be a problem with the integer you are passing in. I bet you are passing in zero, which doesn't work and gives the error you are seeing!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
int val = 16;
TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromHours(val);
string fromTimeString = result.ToString("hh':'mm");
```

Actually, I don't think DateTime is the correct type to represent your need, as you only care about the time within a day. A date also represents the day, and you cannot truncate it (as far as I know).

See [TimeSpan.FromHours Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx)

Comment: I am having Time field in MYSql db . Will this work with it ?

Comment: I don't know, but it looks like the time type is closer to the Timespan type in .Net than Datetime.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do would be something like:

```
DateTime time = Date.Today + new TimeSpan (0, 0, seconds);
```

Answer (score 3):

It can only fail due to two possible reasons.

- First your `fromTime` is holding single digit integer, from `0` to `9`, and since its `9` not `09` it would fail with format `HH`.
- Second reason could be if the integer is greater than `23` or less than `0`.

You can modify your format to single digit `H` which would work for both.

```
DateTime fromTimeDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fromTime.ToString(), "H", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   //fromTime holds one of the integer value.
```

The above would parse any number from `0` to `23`.

By the way it more looks like `TimeSpan` then `DateTime`, you can convert it to `TimeSpan` using [TimeSpan.FromHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx) method.

```
int fromTime = 23;
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(fromTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

The "HH" format needs two digits, and `09` as integer is just "9".

Use a `fromTime.ToString("00")` there to force a leading 0.

Note that the *date* part of that DateTime will be "today".

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written is correct please check once...........

**"fromTime" values may be single digit like "6" instead "06" or "0" or "Other number more than 24"**

"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." You will get this error when you use "hh" instead "HH" in below line ..............

```
DateTime fromTimeDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fromTime.ToString(), "HH", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually *have* an int representing hours, you should not need to do any parsing at all:

```
int hour = 23;
var today = DateTime.Today;
var time = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, hour, 0, 0);
```

Or (slightly modified version of @gean08's answer above):

```
var time = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromHours(hour);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public string timeformat(int time) {
    string hr, min;
    min = Convert.ToString(time % 100);
    hr = Convert.ToString(time / 100);
    if (hr.Length == 1) hr = "0" + hr;
    if (min.Length == 1) min = "0" + min;
    return hr + ":" + min;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please? 'Teach a man to fish' etc.

Comment: mine? you want me to explain?

Comment: if you give a  integer  value 
for example 1020 it will be returning a string value 10:20.........
It will work even if u give 920 ...It will return 09:20

Answer (score 0):

What type of integer are you attempting to convert? For instance, if your integer represents epoch timestamps, like in the example below

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_on": "1711578241"
}
```

You could convert it to a datetime using .NET Core 2.1 or newer, like this:

```
var expires_on = "1711578241"; // epoch timestamp returned by JWT token
var expirationDateTime = DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(expires_on);
```

This will return "3/27/2024 10:24:01 PM".

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?